# Get Last Word from String in Table

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to get the last word from table `Project` in SQL-Server 2017.

My code is as follows:

```
select 
reverse(substring(reverse(ProjectDescription),1, charindex(' ', reverse(ProjectDescription)) -1)) as LastWord
from Project
```

The code works if I ask isolate the table to a single line, but I need the last word for all lines in the field `ProjectDescription`.

When I run the code as above, I get the following error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Please can someone assist me on where I am going wrong.

Comment: You probably need to check the length of the string before you extract the substring - it may not have a space for example so your second parameter to `charindex` might be zero. Use a `case/when` function to check for the existence of space.

Comment: Thank you Peter! It was just one line that had a single word that was causing the issue. Case When sorted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Late answer, posted only as guidance.**

There is no need to split the string.  Your error was simply because charindex() returned a zero.   The simple fix is to add a "***fail-safe***" in the charindex() by adding a space to the string, thus ensuring a hit.

Furthermore, please pay attention to Sean's advice.  I had a similar split function years ago, and was amazed at the performance gains.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[ProjectDescription] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Some Project Item or Description') -- Multiword strubg
,(2,'OneWord    ')                      -- One word with trailing blanks
,(3,NULL)                               -- A NULL value
,(4,'')                                 -- An Empty String

Select * 
      ,LastWord = right(rtrim([ProjectDescription]),charindex(' ',reverse(rtrim([ProjectDescription]))+' ')-1)
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  ProjectDescription                  LastWord
1   Some Project Item or Description    Description
2   OneWord                             OneWord
3   NULL                                NULL
4
```

Comment: Was not my intent to change the ACCEPT

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of a table valued function to split the list into an ordered list. And then only take the the last one using rownumber.

Here is a function. there are lot of these out there.

```
create FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
       ct int
      ,Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT,@ct int =0

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)
            set @ct=@ct+1

            INSERT INTO @Output(Ct,Item)
            SELECT @ct,SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO
```

This is set up so I have a table to use. You would sub this out for your table.

```
declare @t as table(sentence varchar(max))

insert into @t
values
('The brown dog jumped over the fence')
,('This is the final word')
```

Here's the SQL to extract the last word:

```
select *
from (
        select * ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by sentence order by ct desc)
        from @t t
            cross apply dbo.splitstring(t.sentence,' ')
    ) a
where rn=1
```

Results:

```
sentence                            ct  Item    rn
The brown dog jumped over the fence 7   fence   1
This is the final word              5   word    1
```

Comment: This function is horribly inefficient. Multi-statement table valued functions are even slower than scalar functions. There are far better ways to split strings than using loops. [This one](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) or any of [these](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) or even the built in [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I agree I grabbed a basic one. The function wasn't really part of the question. My preference is the xml one as I am still in SQL 2012

Comment: @KeithL here is one for older versions that is lightning fast too. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function

Comment: And yes I know wasn't part of the question, but it was an integral part of your solution. I can't see that kind of splitter be posted and not say something. :)

Answer (score 1):

select Ltrim(Rtrim(Right([ProjectDescription], (CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE([ProjectDescription])))))) from Project

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple function:

```
create function dbo.getLastWord(@s varchar(100))
returns varchar(200)
as
begin
declare @i int
set @i=len(@s)
 while substring(@s,@i,1)<>' '
  set @i=@i-1
 return substring(@s,@i,len(@s)-@i+1)
end
```

And call it:

```
select dbo.getLastWord('Feels things getting better')
```

which gets:

```
better
```

Answer (score 0):

remove (-1) from end then execute.

```
select 
reverse(substring(reverse(ProjectDescription),1, charindex(' ', reverse(ProjectDescription)))) as LastWord
from Project
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest I have come up with:

```
SELECT Reverse(JSON_VALUE('["' + REPLACE(Reverse('1A.2b.33C.44D4.55E'),'.','","') + '"]','$[0]'))
```

Answer (score -1):

answer above works great for me after adding the -1 for anyone looking at this at later date: (see -1 inserted below)

```
UPPER(reverse(substring(reverse(ProjectDescription),1, charindex(' ', reverse(ProjectDescription))-1))
```