# Remove last word from string in one column and put as string in existing empty column when the first column has more than one word? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server

I have this:

[image]

And I want this:

[image]

Does anybody know how that can be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Last Word from String in Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58438406/2029983)

Comment: SQL Server has a bunch of helpful string functions. I recommend checking them out, having a go, and posting where you get stuck.

Comment: Larnu, yes that is helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following approach. It is based on use of XML and XQuery.

XML and XQuery data model is based on **ordered sequences**. That's why it is so easy to get position of any item in a sequence: first, last, etc.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl  TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Street VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Street) VALUES
('SANDISLE DR.'),
('TAMMY LANE'),
('OLD OREGON TRAIL'),
('ELTEDA'),
('PAROCAR ROAD');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
           REPLACE(Street, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
           ']]></r></root>' AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID, Street
, xmldata.query('if (count(/root/r) gt 1) then data(/root/r[position() ne last()]) 
    else data(/root/r[1])').value('(.)', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS StreetName
, xmldata.query('if (count(/root/r) gt 1) then data(/root/r[last()])
    else ()').value('(.)', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS StreetSuffix
FROM rs;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------------+------------+--------------+
| ID |      Street      | StreetName | StreetSuffix |
+----+------------------+------------+--------------+
|  1 | SANDISLE DR.     | SANDISLE   | DR.          |
|  2 | TAMMY LANE       | TAMMY      | LANE         |
|  3 | OLD OREGON TRAIL | OLD OREGON | TRAIL        |
|  4 | ELTEDA           | ELTEDA     |              |
|  5 | PAROCAR ROAD     | PAROCAR    | ROAD         |
+----+------------------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Your script worked fine for me.  I just updated it.

Comment: @ASH, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.