# query lookup table without key join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to create a table lists that lookup to another table. for example

Table A

| AMOUNT | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | i want eat |
| 2000 | i want sleep |

table b(lookup)

| SEARCH | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| eat | go to eat |
| sleep | go to sleep |

expected result

| Amount | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | go to eat |
| 2000 | go to sleep |

I tried query like this but still didn't work

```
SELECT amount, IIF(description like '%(select search from table b)%',(select activity from table b), null) as activity
FROM table a
```

Comment: For this specific case, you need to write a string expression that converts `'i want to eat'` to `'eat'`. This shows some examples of how to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58438406/get-last-word-from-string-in-table

Comment: Why don't you go with a scalar valued function that searches in Table B with description as a parameter and returns the corresponding activity if it is a match ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular join as well

```
SELECT a.amount, b.activity 
FROM tableA a
JOIN lookupTable b on a.description like '%' + b.search + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, but you'll have to think, as the comments say, how you really want to "parse" A.Description

```
select A.Amount,B.Activity
from 
    tableA A
    inner join tableB B on B.Search = stuff(A.Description,1,7,'') -- remove first 7 chars
```